# Access output of AWS lambda.invoke method outside the method

Tags: javascript, aws-lambda

I am invoking a lambda function through javascript using AWS SDK. I am referring this AWS documentation to implement this: https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/tree/main/javascript/example_code/lambda/lambda-for-browser
I am able to invoke the method successfully as I am able to see the lambda function response in console.log(data) output within the invoke method. How do I access this 'data' outside the invoke method?

````
            // Initialize the Amazon Cognito credentials provider.
            

            const params = {
                FunctionName: 'LambdaFunctionName',
                InvocationType: "RequestResponse",
            };

            lambda.invoke(params,  function (err, data){
                if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
                else console.log(data);          // successful response
                });```


Note: I am not using node.js
````

Answer (score 0):

You can return a promise from the invokeFunction, In the below example, the invokeLambdaAsync function returns a Promise that resolves with the data when the Lambda function is successfully invoked or rejects with an error if an error occurs. You can then use .then() to handle the response and access the data variable outside the lambda.invoke method.

```
const params = {
    FunctionName: 'LambdaFunctionName',
    InvocationType: "RequestResponse",
};

function invokeLambdaAsync(params) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        lambda.invoke(params, (err, data) => {
            if (err) {
                reject(err);
            } else {
                resolve(data);
            }
        });
    });
}

invokeLambdaAsync(params)
    .then(data => {
        console.log("Lambda response:", data);
        // You can access the 'data' variable here
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.error("Error invoking Lambda:", err);
    });
```

you can also use invoke().promise() to work with Promises and async/await directly when using the AWS SDK for JavaScript (v2)

```
const params = {
    FunctionName: 'LambdaFunctionName',
    InvocationType: "RequestResponse",
};

const invokeLambda = async (params) => {
    try {
        const data = await lambda.invoke(params).promise();
        console.log("Lambda response:", data);
        // You can access the 'data' variable here
    } catch (err) {
        console.error("Error invoking Lambda:", err);
    }
};

invokeLambda(params);
```